# Is it possible to monitor Windows Services with Perfino and Zipkin?

Tags: windows, service, zipkin, perfino

I want to monitor some Windows Services with either perfino or Zipkin. Does anyone know if that is possible?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have the ability to specify VM parameters, you can add the monitoring agent, regardless of the whether the JVM is started as a Windows service. For perfino, that VM parameter is

```
-javaagent:[path to perfino.jar]
```